# How would you store a recipe inside a json?

Tags: javascript, json

How would you store a recipe inside a json? I was thinking of storing a recipe, and I was thinking of doing it this way:

```
const recipes = {{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Omelette',
    recipe: 'Do something /n
    Do something else /n
    Do something else after that /n
    Do something else after that',
    ingredients: 'Ingredient1 /n
    Ingredient2 /n
    Ingredient3 /n',
    date: '',
}}
```

I was thinking of doing it this way, but I am wondering if there's a better way. Should I put the line skip inside like that or is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: #1 what do you mean by "line skip inside" #2 Are you planning to store this json in some database? #3 Are you open to a more normalized structure?

Comment: #1, using /n, #2 maybe, #3 i am open to anything that's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiline in json is complex to create and maintain. Also if you are planning to store it in some database, a normalized entity will be better:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Omelette",
  "date": "",
  "recipeSteps": [
    "Do something",
    "Do something else",
    "Do something else after that",
    "Do something else after that"
  ],
  "ingredients": [
    "Ingredient1",
    "Ingredient2",
    "Ingredient3"
  ]
}
```

If order of the recipe steps is a concern for you:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Omelette",
  "date": "",
  "recipeSteps": {
    "0": "Do something",
    "1": "Do something else",
    "2": "Do something else after that",
    "3": "Do something else after that"
  },
  "ingredients": [
    "Ingredient1",
    "Ingredient2",
    "Ingredient3"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in JSON your recipes  would be like

```
const myObj = {recipes :[{"id":0,
                title: 'Omelette',
                 contents:["something","something"],
                 ingredients:["ing1","ing2"],
                 date: ''
                },
                {"id":1,
                 title: 'anything',
                 contents:["something","something"],
                 ingredients:["ing1","ing2"],
                 date: ''
                }
]};
```

this enables you to know how many recipes you or recipe's contents or ingredients

```
myObj.recipes.length
```

or

```
myObj.recipes[0].contents.length
```

and can access any recipes by its index which you can set the id as its index to easily access it

```
myObj.recipes[0].ingredients
```

by this line you can get an array of ingredients which would be easy to use than using string to store data like in your example.
so if you would modify one ingredient you just need to change this specific one like

```
myObj.recipes[0].ingredients[1]="new ing";
```